# Outlook macro save attachment is not working - Kaspersky maybe

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a problem with saving attachment from Outlook - I am using this macro with outlook rule and I distributed it to my colleagues. Suddenly macro stopped working but nothing changed in macro or outlook settings. Could it be Kaspersky is preventing saving attachment to disk ?

```
Public Sub saveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    sSaveFolder = "C:\D\"
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: no, nothing, attachment is simply not there

Comment: Any difference if you use FileName instead of DisplayName?

Comment: I am not sure if this helped but I enabled in File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Email Security - Allow Script in shared Folders and also Allow Script in Public Folders